# Php replace the last space in the label

Tags: php

I have this string :

```
[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de ","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545926599900"}]
```

I need to delete the last space from the label, the actual value is "Champ Date de " i need to convert it as "Champ Date de".

Here my actual code :

```
        $form = str_replace('\n','',$request->getParameter('data'));
        $form = str_replace('\t','',$form);
        $form = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$form);
        $form = str_replace('<br>','',$form);
        var_dump($form); die;
```

The problem come from the 
  : `str_replace('<br>','',$form);`

with `&nbsp;` i have no problem and the function str_replace do not add a space. but with `<br>` the str_replace add a space add i really need to have any space at the end of this value. hope someone could help.

I could have multiple array :

```
'[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de ","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545929424866"},{"type":"checkbox-group","label":"You like it ? ","name":"checkbox-group-1545929428281","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"1","selected":true}]}]'
```

Comment: Can you not just `trim($form)` as the last operation?

Comment: Try [`trim()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), it will remove all white space from the beginning and the end, except for the `<br>`

Comment: yes i tried but when i do that i get "ChampDatede" instead of "Champ Date de"

Comment: @MathieuMourareau That is simply imposible...

Comment: Though, if you're trying to trim it from the middle of the json, it would be better to use `json_decode`, then go through and trim all the values.

Comment: Is there any issue with `json_decode()`-ing it, target the value your wish to trim, apply `trim()`, and `json_encode()` it back to a string?

Comment: I think you are getting the string without space because of all those `str_replace` you are using

Comment: Did you try [``rtrim``](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) ? It remove only spaces at the end of your string

Comment: `str_replace` can use an array, so you only need one call. Do you have the literal characters in your string? `\n` in single quotes is just that, in double quotes it is a new line. Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53948015/php-replace-the-last-space-in-the-label#comment94734596_53948015 is the best idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this **non-regex** way with `array_map('trim',$array);`?

```
<?php
$json = '[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de ","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545926599900"}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1)[0];
$array= array_map('trim',$array);
echo json_encode([$array]);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545926599900"}]
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/qJ9K1

**EDIT:** As per OP's comment

```
<?php
$json = '[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de ","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545929424866"},{"type":"checkbox-group","label":"You like it ? ","name":"checkbox-group-1545929428281","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"1","selected":true}]}]';
$array = json_decode($json,1);
$expected = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $key=>$value){
        if($key == 'label' && !is_array($value)){
          $expected[$k][$key]= trim($value); 
       }else{
          $expected[$k][$key]= $value; 
       }
    }
}

echo json_encode($expected);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/NRlsR

Comment: thanks for your reply it's working but i can have multiple array. i update the post with the exemple with multiple array

Comment: @MathieuMourareau then you can do it using 2 `foreach()`. See my edit and let me know is that worked for you or not now?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without loop by using regex
Here is the solution:

```
$string = '[{"type":"date","label":"Champ Date de ","className":"form-control","name":"date-1545929424866"},{"type":"checkbox-group","label":"You like it ? ","name":"checkbox-group-1545929428281","values":[{"label":"Option 1","value":"1","selected":true}]}]';
$pattern = '/("label":"([\w\s])+)/m';
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($match) {return trim($match[0]);}, $string);
```

I have done echo for the result. You just need to assign it to a variable.